# Matrix of rotation of center $y$ and angle $\theta$

Tags: solution-verification, linear-transformations, rotations

Fix a real number $\theta$. Let $s_{y}$ be a rotation of $S^{2}$ with center $y \in S^{2}$ and  angle $\theta$.

My question is how can we define the map $s_y$?

My attempt :
Let
$s_{y}: \quad S^{2} \longrightarrow S^{2} : x\longrightarrow s_{y}(x)=y+Ax$
with

$$A=
\begin{pmatrix}\cos \theta & -\sin \theta & 0 \\ 
\sin \theta & \cos \theta & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
Is my solution true? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It would rather be $s_y(x)=y+A(x-y)$ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: There isn't a unique rotation with center $y$ and angle $\theta$. So your definition of $s_y$ is incomplete. Or you should say "Let $s_y$ be $\color{red}{\text{a}}$ rotation ..."

Comment: thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$s_y: x \mapsto y + A(x-y)$

First, translate to the center. Then rotate. Then translate back.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, I understood .